# Get 8 digit binary from char in c# win. form

Tags: c#, winforms, binary

How to get **8 digit binary from char** in c# win. form?

Like if i write **D** it should return **01000100** and 
     if i write **T** it should return **01010100**

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: i want char to be converted to 0's and 1's

Comment: `var s = Convert.ToString((byte)ch, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');`  You can't turn that in for your homework assignment btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char c = 'D';
string s = Convert.ToString(c,2); // results in "1000100"
string s2 = s.PadLeft(8, '0'); // results in "01000100"
```

---

OP asked for a faster solution, so I suggest a pre-calculated lookup table

```
string[] binaries = new string[256];

// Calulate all 8 bit decimal string representations. 
// Do this once, on initialization.
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    binaries[i] = Convert.ToString(i,2).PadLeft(8, '0');
}

// Get the representation for a character.
char c = 'D';
string s = binaries[c];
```

Comment: this worked fine but is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: I doubt it. Are you sure this is a critical bottleneck in your performance?

Comment: yes sir you are right this is the thing that is making my performance weak.

Comment: In that case, you could create a pre-calculated lookup table: use the code above to calculate the binary representation for all possible characters and store them in an array, so you can just lookup the value instead of calculating it every time.

Comment: my friend i have already tried this solution but as soon as my exe is started i need to get binaries and there is no time for pre-calculation

Comment: The pre-calculation takes 0.00003 seconds on my machine. That's 3% of a millisecond. I'm having trouble seeing how this could be too slow, for something that only has to run once.